# How to use Expandable RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application i want use category and subCategory for items such as list UI and i get this data from server:

```
    Category1
      |
      |--SubCat1_1
         |
         |--subSubCat1_1
      |
      |--SubCat2
         |
         |--subSubCat1_2_1
         |
         |--subSubCat1_2_2
         |
         |--subSubCat1_2_3
    Category2
      |
      |--SubCat2_1
         |
         |--subSubCat2_1
      |
      |--SubCat2_2
         |
         |--subSubCat2_2_1
         |
         |--subSubCat2_2_2
         |
         |--subSubCat2_2_3

and more ...
```

for this i want `RecyclerView`, but i don't know how can it?

How can i it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)

And here is some of its usage and you can find more tips in the link above:

Let's say you are a rock star :guitar: and you want to build an app to show a list of your favorite Genres with a list of their top Artists.

First, define your custom ExpandableGroup class:

```
public class Genre extends ExpandableGroup<Artist> {

public Genre(String title, List<Artist> items) {
    super(title, items);
  }
}
```

Next up, let's create the ChildViewHolder and GroupViewHolder. These are both wrappers around regular ol' RecyclerView.ViewHolders so implement any view inflation and binding methods you may need.

```
public class GenreViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder

  private TextView genreTitle;

  public GenreViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    genreTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre_title);
  }

  public void setGenreTitle(ExpandableGroup group) {
    genreTitle.setText(group.getTitle());
  }
}
public class ArtistViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

  private TextView artistName;

  public ArtistViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    artistName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
  }

  public void onBind(Artist artist) {
    artistName.setText(artist.getTitle());
  }
}
```

Now we are ready for the juicy part - let's make our ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter

By including your GroupViewHolder and ChildViewHolder in the definition of the class, you'll see that the onCreateGroupViewHolder and onCreateChildViewHolder methods return the correct type :+1:

```
public class GenreAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<GenreViewHolder, ArtistViewHolder> {

  public GenreAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
    super(groups);
  }

  @Override
  public GenreViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_genre, parent, false);
    return new GenreViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public ArtistViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_artist, parent, false);
    return new ArtistViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindChildViewHolder(ArtistViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group,
      int childIndex) {
    final Artist artist = ((Artist) group).getItems().get(childIndex);
    holder.setArtistName(artist.getName());
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindGroupViewHolder(GenreViewHolder holder, int flatPosition,
      ExpandableGroup group) {
    holder.setGenreTitle(group);
  }
}
```

Lastly let's you'll need either an Activity or Fragment to host your adapter. Once you've got that up and running, all that's left if to instantiate your fancy new GenreAdapter with a List

```
public class GenreActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    List<Genre> genres = getGenres();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    //instantiate your adapter with the list of genres
    GenreAdapter adapter = new GenreAdapter(genres);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...

  }
}
```

If you want to save the expand and collapse state of your adapter, you have to explicitly call through to the adapters `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`in the calling Activity

```
public class GenreActivity extends Activity {

  ...

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    adapter.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    adapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

**Listening to Expand/Collapse events**

If you want register an ExpandCollapseListener outside of the adapter, you can simply call setOnGroupExpandCollapseListener on the ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter

```
adapter.setOnGroupExpandCollapseListener(new GroupExpandCollapseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(ExpandableGroup group) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(ExpandableGroup group) {

    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i use subSubCategory?

Comment: How to make that first group should be expanded by default.